# How to find permutations of a string with all distinct characters?

Tags: java, string, recursion

I have found a piece of code in a book which claims to print all permutations of a string with all distinct characters :-

```
void permutation(String str) {
    permutation(str, "");
}
    
void permutation(String str, String prefix) {
    if (str.length() == 0) {
        System.out.println(prefix);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            String rem = str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i + 1);
            permutation(rem, prefix + str.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

What is the role of the rem variable in the code?

Comment: Take a string like `"abc"` and go with it through the function. Try to understand each step in the code. Take a paper and write down partial results.

Comment: You are aware of the method `permutation(String, String)` calling itself with adjusted arguments under certain conditions, aren't you?

Comment: I dont understand the String rem = something. why this rem is required at all?

Comment: @Jeet It's not "required" but this temporary variable makes the code a little bit more readable. You could write everything in the `permutation`-call but it'd be a pretty long statement.

Comment: No I mean
String rem = str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i + 1);
is always producing the same string isnt it? suppose "abc" is our string then everytime it is going to assign "abc" to rem.

Comment: Check the [javadoc for `substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-):  `str.substring(0,i) + str.substring(i +1)` actually gives `str` with the `i`'th character removed.

Comment: No, this will produce different results as ``permutation`` is called recursively. You should run this code in a debugger to see.

Comment: @KevinAnderson - Oh ! Thanks a lot! It excludes the end index basically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can visualize the process.

```
static int indent = 0;
static String indent(int i) { return "  ".repeat(i); }

void permutation(String str) {
    System.out.println("permutation(\"" + str + "\")");
    ++indent;
    permutation(str, "");
}


void permutation(String str, String prefix) {
    System.out.println(indent(indent) + "permutation(\"" + str + "\", \"" + prefix + "\")");
    if (str.length() == 0) {
        System.out.println(indent(indent + 1) + "--> "+ prefix);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            String rem = str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i + 1);
            ++indent;
            permutation(rem, prefix + str.charAt(i));
            --indent;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
permutation("abc");
```

output

```
permutation("abc")
  permutation("abc", "")
    permutation("bc", "a")
      permutation("c", "ab")
        permutation("", "abc")
          --> abc
      permutation("b", "ac")
        permutation("", "acb")
          --> acb
    permutation("ac", "b")
      permutation("c", "ba")
        permutation("", "bac")
          --> bac
      permutation("a", "bc")
        permutation("", "bca")
          --> bca
    permutation("ab", "c")
      permutation("b", "ca")
        permutation("", "cab")
          --> cab
      permutation("a", "cb")
        permutation("", "cba")
          --> cba
```